# How to delete record from table using Angular http.delete with PHP backend?

Tags: php, angular, angular-http

I am trying to delete a record from the database table using Angular on frontend and PHP on the backend. I am passing the `id` through URL and trying to get it back with `$_GET['id']` but it doesn't work (no error in console).

PHP API:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require_once("includes/initialize.php");

$db = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase) or die('Could not connect to database');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$id;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}


// update the ECD
if(ECD::deleteECD($id)){
    echo '{';
    echo '"message": "The center was deleted."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to update the ECD, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
    echo '"message": "Unable to delete the center."';
    echo '}';
}
```

And Angular http.delete:

```
deleteCenter (id: number): Observable<{}> {
  const url = `${this.D_ROOT_URL}${id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url);
}
```

I tested the URL to make sure it's passing the correct URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete() method returns a cold observable, which means that the HTTP request is not sent until someone subscribes to the observable. You should write this:

`return this.http.delete(url).subscribe();`

Comment: I confirm this behavior. For testing purposes, I left out the `.subscribe()` part in the component and it sent the HTTP request to the service and stopped there. From within the service, it didn't even send the HTTP request to the backend. Logging the delete parameter in the service proved the same. Monitoring the `Network` tab in the browser console proved that the API was not hit and hence the delete operation was never performed.